# arcpy.FieldMappings renames input fields internally

Tags: arcpy, field-mapping

I'm trying to make use of Field mappings to merge many datasets into a new one... as per the manual.

```
   ... 
   print (type(idealFieldList))   # class 'list'

   # let's prune the fluff

   fieldmappings=arcpy.FieldMappings()
   fcSources = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Source*", "Polygon")
   for fc in fcSources:
       print (fc + " is being absorbed..", end='')        
       fieldmappings.addTable(fc)       # but something else is happening here....

   fieldMaps=fieldmappings.fieldMappings
   print ("Done. \nAll fieldmaps have been acquired")


   # let's drop the unwanted fields
   for eachfld in fieldMaps:
       outf=eachfld.outputField
       if outf.name in idealFieldList:
            #do nothing
            print (outf.name + " ------------> is ok")
       else: 
            print (outf.name + " must go")
```

OUTPUT:

```
ContactName_1 must go
ContactName_12 must go
ContactName_12_13 must go
ContactName_12_13_14 must go
ContactName_12_13_14_15 must go
ContactName_12_13_14_15_16 must go
```

The problem is this line `fieldmappings.addTable(fc) # but something else is happening here....`

I have 6 source feature classes, all of them have a field called "ContactName". In my fieldMappings, after they have been added, I find the field name has been altered as shown above in the output.

I thought the whole point of FieldMappings was that I would have a single output fieldname "ContactName" and that single output would have 6 inputs that are it's origin.

How do I do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not constructing the field mapping correctly. It's quite fiddly to set up but once you have done it, it is very powerful way of bringing datasets together be it a Merge or Spatial Join.

I recently had to merge many dbf files, the product of some zonal statistics analysis I had done. Below is a function that takes a list of files and constructs a field mapping which is passes back. Read the comments and understand the sequence. You can use this as a template for building your own fieldmapping:

```py
def ConstructFieldMappings(fnList):
    '''
        This function builds the field mapping object that feeds into the Merge tool. If code fails it returns None

        Note we drop the ZONE_COUNT field in the output field mappings
    '''
    try:
        fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

        fieldmap_TOID = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap_COUNT = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap_AREA = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap_MIN = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap_MAX = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap_MEAN = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap_BUFFERID = arcpy.FieldMap()

        # Load the input tables and their matching field into their respective field map object
        for fn in fnList:
            fieldmap_TOID.addInputField(fn,"toid",-1,-1)
            fieldmap_COUNT.addInputField(fn,"COUNT",-1,-1)
            fieldmap_AREA.addInputField(fn,"AREA",-1,-1)
            fieldmap_MIN.addInputField(fn,"MIN",-1,-1)
            fieldmap_MAX.addInputField(fn,"MAX",-1,-1)
            fieldmap_MEAN.addInputField(fn,"MEAN",-1,-1)
            fieldmap_BUFFERID.addInputField(fn,"BufferID",-1,-1)

        # Create the output fields, these are the fields that end up in the output table
        outField1 = arcpy.Field()
        outField1.name = "TOID"
        outField1.type = "String"
        outField1.length = 20
        outField1.isNullable = True
        outField3 = arcpy.Field()
        outField3.name =  "COUNT"
        outField3.type = "Integer"
        outField3.precision = 10
        outField3.isNullable = True
        outField4 = arcpy.Field()
        outField4.name = "AREA"
        outField4.type = "Double"
        outField4.isNullable = True
        outField4.precision = 0
        outField4.scale = 0
        outField5 = arcpy.Field()
        outField5.name = "MIN"
        outField5.type = "Double"
        outField5.isNullable = True
        outField5.precision = 0
        outField5.scale = 0
        outField6 = arcpy.Field()
        outField6.name = "MAX"
        outField6.type = "Double"
        outField6.isNullable = True
        outField6.precision = 0
        outField6.scale = 0
        outField7 = arcpy.Field()
        outField7.name = "MEAN"
        outField7.type = "Double"
        outField7.isNullable = True
        outField7.precision = 0
        outField7.scale = 0
        outField8 = arcpy.Field()
        outField8.name = "BUFFER_ID"
        outField8.type = "SmallInteger"
        outField8.isNullable = True
        outField8.precision = 4

        # For each field map set its output field
        fieldmap_TOID.outputField = outField1
        fieldmap_COUNT.outputField = outField3
        fieldmap_AREA.outputField = outField4
        fieldmap_MIN.outputField = outField5
        fieldmap_MAX.outputField = outField6
        fieldmap_MEAN.outputField = outField7
        fieldmap_BUFFERID.outputField = outField8

        # For each field map set its default merge rule
        fieldmap_TOID.mergeRule = "First"
        fieldmap_COUNT.mergeRule = "First"
        fieldmap_AREA.mergeRule = "First"
        fieldmap_MIN.mergeRule = "First"
        fieldmap_MAX.mergeRule = "First"
        fieldmap_MEAN.mergeRule = "First"
        fieldmap_BUFFERID.mergeRule = "First"

        # Add the individual field maps to the the fieldmappings object, it's this that is supplied to the Merge tool
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_TOID)
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_COUNT)
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_AREA)
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_MIN)
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_MAX)
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_MEAN)
        fieldMappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap_BUFFERID)

        # return field mapings object
        return fieldMappings
    except Exception as e:
        # Some error occured
        print("Last processing file was " + fn)
        print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
        print(str(e))
        return None
```